# what does SetProperty of solr.home do in Solr?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, nutch

I am trying to index some documents for search engine in Solr. 
in my piece of code, here is a part that I do nit understand:

```
System.SetProperty("solr.solr.home", "/home/emre/solr");
CoreContainer.Initializer Initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
```

what does CoreContainer do? what does the first line of the code mean?

Answer (score 1):

**solr.solr.home** points to the root of all your collections (**not** solr installation). There is a **solr.xml** there that defines global configuration. Under it - usually immediately but can be at any depth - there would be directories containing **core.properties** files, whose presence identify the root of the actual individual collection/core.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `EmbeddedSolrServer`.

> The EmbeddedSolrServer class provides an implementation of the
>   SolrClient client API talking directly to an micro-instance of Solr
>   running directly in your Java application.

`solr.solr.home` sets where the solr is installed.

you should read more about this here 
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer

Also just so that you know The use of EmbeddedSolrServer is not recommended.

Read here https://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr